# R - Recoding data frame with a key vector

Tags: r

I have this vector:

```
key <- c(2,1,3,2,3,3,3,1,1,3,1,3,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,3,1,3,2,2,1,3,2,2,2,3)
```

And a data frame like this:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30
1  1  1  4  3  4  3  1  2   2   4   2   2   1   2   3   2   4   2   2   1   2   3   2   1   4   2   1   4   3
1  1  3  2  3  2  1  1  2   1   3   2   2   3   1   2   1   4   1   2   2   4   3   4   1   3   3   4   4   4
2  1  1  2  1  3  3  1  2   1   1   2   3   1   1   3   1   2   2   3   1   3   2   2   1   3   2   3   2   3
```

How could I convert the data frame into 0 and 1 using the key vector for recoding the data?

If data coincides with the vector key a 1 should appear, else should appear a 0

The first case should look like this:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30
 0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1
```

Comment: Try `+(df == key[col(df)])`. I think you have mistakes in `V5`, `V15`, `V16`, etc.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for your help!